# Print not centered

Tags: slic3r

I have a Colido 2.0 printer that I cannot seem to get a print centered on the plate. I am using Slic3r and OctoPrint. If I use Repetier Host directly connected, I can get it to print correctly. I'm guessing Slic3r is the culprit but I can't find where. Any suggestions?

Can't post a picture of the actual print. It is printing partially off what would be the left side of the bed according to Slic3r.

[image: slic3r centered]

[image: screenshot of the bed shape graphical user interface]

Comment: Please clarify: when directly connected, what software is doing the slicing?  When NOT directly connected, can you get the G-code file RepetierHost is using loaded onto your USB stick and run that way?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft when directly connected, I had switched it to curaengine. I did export that gcode file, upload to octoprint and had it print correctly. octoprint still showed it as being off the plate.

Comment: Why don't you check your Slic3r settings -> Printer Setting -> general for values in Bed Size and Print Center fields for correctness?

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshots of the bed shape can be seen that the bed size is defined as 228 x 150 mm with a definition of the origin at (0, 0).

From an [internet search](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012UC7T1I) the bed size of the Colido 2.0 is found to be  225 x 145 x 150 mm. This implies that the current setup is slightly incorrect.

Note that this needs to coincide with the way the firmware has been configured. The [accepted answer](/a/11259/) on question: ["What determines print start location on the build plate?"](/q/11228) shows that the origin not necessarily need to be at the corner of the build plate, it can also be at the center; this depends on the firmware brand. [This answer](/a/11243) explains that you can find out where the origin is located. Basically, you need to prepare a G-code file containing at least homing (`G28`), optionally bed levelling if your printer has auto bed levelling (`G29`) and a move to the origin (`G1 X0 Y0 Z15 F500`); *note a Z of 15 is chosen for safety!*. You can edit an existing G-code file for this or create a new text file from scratch saving the file with a `.g` extension. When this is "printed"/executed, the nozzle should be at the (elevated, so X, Y) origin as defined by your firmware. Usually this is at the left front corner of your build plate (there may be clips there, so therefore the elevated value), but can also be the center of the plate.

If the nozzle centers in the middle of the build plate, the bed shape configuration should be altered to put the origin in the center of the build plate, so 225/2=112.5 for X and 145/2=72.5 for Y.

Comment: I was using what was included with the printer. I'll adjust accordingly and also try the "finding origin" gcode. thank you!